# Why does href (using thymeleaf) show a "?" in the address after clicking the html link provided by href even though there is no "?" in href?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I would like to generate links in my html page using thymeleaf with the address http://localhost:8080/book/{key}. However, it always shows the address with an extra question mark instead http://localhost:8080/book/?{key}. Is it because my syntax is wrong in the html page? How can I change my html page so that it does not show the question mark?

P.S. key comes from a list of keys provided in a list of *existingTitle*

```
<ol style="padding-top:1em">
   <span th:each="t : ${existingTitle}">
      <a th:href="@{book/(${t[0]})}">
         <li th:text="${t[1]}" style="padding-top:0.5em"></li></a>
   </span>
</ol>
```

[image: This image shows that when I hover over my link, the link pops up with an extra question mark.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you pass `t[0]` as parameter and not as path. Check [absolute path](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#absolute-urls) and [adding parameters](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#adding-parameters) sections in documentation.

So your link should like this

```
<a th:href="@{book/{id}(id=${t[0]})}">
```

*or*

```
<a th:href="@{book/${t[0]}}">
```

Comment: <a th:href="@{book/{id}(id=${t[0]})}"> this works! Thank you very much.

Interestingly, <a th:href="@{book/${t[0]}}"> doesn't work. Apparently, somehow, html does not process ${t[0]} in this syntax properly and the value of t[0] comes out gibberish.

Comment: @XIII Maybe, I have never used thymeleaf, just read documentation

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to Justinas's post, and my subsequent reply, using
"`a th:href="@{book/${t[0]}}"`" causes the value of `t[0]` to be gibberish, like in this image :

[image: 1]